# Ага, нашел! Что мне за это будет?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто я не знаю кому сообщить. А, может быть, я не прав?

P. S. Насчет "Что мне за это будет?" — это, конечно, шутка, просто в глаза бросилось.

Upd.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А "коммент**ра**иев" не смутило?

Comment: Да нормально, и так сойдет)

Comment: Передам отзыв администраторам. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки были исправлены!

Благодарим за помощь!

Comment: Приятно помочь хорошим людям)